# How to debug plugins?

Tags: java, user-interface, debugging, netbeans, plugins

I'm working on a project for class that involves me developing a plugin for an existing application. However, I struggle with GUI programming and the inability to use a debugger or print statements has made the process very not fun. Is there any way I can debug this thing other than trial and error?

The plugin (as well as the main program) are written in Java, and I'm using NetBeans. I'd prefer to stick with NetBeans but would be willing to move to a different IDE if necessary.

Comment: How to debug? Step through line by line, compare values. Write some unit tests etc. Not much to say more, it's pretty trivial.

Comment: I know how to debug. I'm trying to figure out how to debug a .jar file that is executed by (and is dependent on the resources of) another .jar file. As in, if you have program A which executes program B, and program B cannot execute if program A isn't running, how do you debug program B?

Comment: Unless you can decompile the jar it will be nearly impossible to debug line by line.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use remote debugging as described here http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDebuggingRemote

This involves running the original JAR from the command line with the following parameters `"-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8888,suspend=n"

This would then allow you to attach the Netbeans debugger to the running process.